# Access CUPS Server from Express Application in Docker, Ubuntu WSL

Tags: linux, docker, express, server, cups

I'm currently working on getting my Express application to integrate with CUPS for printing files like pdfs. Currently, the idea is that my Express application will eventually be hosted inside its own Docker container, and I need to integrate it with CUPS for printing files. Ive installed cups on my Ubuntu WSL instance and got it printing files. But when going to deploy this system in Docker, should the CUPS web server be its own Docker container? And how would I communicate from the Express docker container to the CUPS server container.

I'm just confused on the architecture about how this system will look like once its set up on Docker, and how it works. I'm learning how to use Docker, so any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If the Express server is invoking CUPS, that would imply that a browser client can ask the server to print something on the server system (not the same place as the browser).  Is that what you actually intend?

Comment: @DavidMaze The whole flow of how things get triggered is that the frontend will also have its own docker container, which communicates with the Express app( which exists in its own docker container as well). So yes, in the frontend will make a request to an endpoint exposed by the Express app, where express is then in charge of printing something using CUPS.

Comment: @DavidMaze The only way I can see doing it (assuming I allow the CUPS server to be in its own container) is to expose an endpoint that the Express app can use to trigger the printing.